# Decode/decompress H.264 back into raw/original file format, then encode into H.265

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, h.265

I have some files encoded using the H.264 codec.

There is a loss of quality when I convert them from H.264 to H.265.

I imagine I should convert them back to raw/original file format, then encode them into H.265.

Is it possible to decompress/decode H.264 into the original format (perhaps using FFMpeg)?

Is it the best way to convert from H.264 to H.265 without quality loss?

Thank you again for your help,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

H.264 is lossy; the quality is lost at encoding time. There is no way to reconstruct the original from encoded form. In contrast, decoding is lossless - it produces exactly all of the information present in H.264 file, no more, no less. If your video editing software is not horrible, your H.264->H.265 conversion is the highest quality you can theoretically achieve given the compression settings you provide (without finding your original uncompressed file); there is no benefit in a separate decoding step, as that is what your software needs to do anyway.

Imagine a bad photocopy: there is no unphotocopier that can give you the original. That's what is happening with lossy compression.

Comment: Thanks Amadan. Do you know if it is possible to convert from H.264 to H.265 without loss of quality?

Comment: I believe so, but with a big "but". When you transcode, decoding does not decrease quality, encoding does if codec is lossless. Since H.265 also has lossless mode, if you use that you should not see any quality drop. However, you might not see any benefit compared to just continuing to use the H.264 file (since it should contain the same data), while I expect file size to increase dramatically (since you are not getting the benefits of lossless encoding) - worst of both worlds.